# Using CSS how can I achieve this result?

Tags: css

How can I create a block of content that has a heading like the one below in the picture?
I have used `5px solid #444751` to do some tests, however I can't get the name aligned to the right and the middle of the line.
Below them I will place an image.

[image]

Comment: A `div` filled with a background colour of black, with the text floated next to it?

Comment: i guess its a progress bar? :) ... use 3 div to achieve the same.. and as said by @ChrisW

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="line"></div>Batteries


.line {
    border-top:5px solid #444751;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-right:5px;   
}
```

Comment: Not crazy about leaving text strings out in the open like that without a container. OP probably wants to do a `text-transform: uppercase`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to align the text with the center of the bar is `vertical-align`. Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxTgf/1/).

Here's the CSS I used

```
#bar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    display:inline-block;
}
#text{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect using gradients. The HTML is minimal:

```
<h1>BATTERIES</h1>
```

And you don't need much CSS either:

```
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 25px;
}
h1:before {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 40%, #000 40%, 
        #000 60%, transparent 60%);
    content:'';
}
```

This is all and you can see it live at http://dabblet.com/gist/2719686

Bear in mind the fact that gradients don't work in IE9 or older.

Comment: Nice one. Didn't know that site, either. Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

split it into two divs like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/hUaht/

Answer (score 0):

A [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/fieldset) can work nicely here, specially if the width of the text is dynamic:

```
<fieldset class="BlackLine">
    <legend>Hello World</legend>
    <div>
        Content
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset.BlackLine {border-style:none; border-top:solid 5px black;direction:rtl;}
fieldset.BlackLine > legend, fieldset.BlackLine > div {direction:ltr;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XY24Q/

Comment: Thank you for this answer. How can I keep a standard width of the block? I mean, the line and the text should not exceed the 400px width

Comment: @Kaoukkos - Like every element, you can set `width:400`, `max-width` or `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .Bat{
                float: left;}
                .Line{
                float: left;
                width:150px;}
                hr{
                height:5px;
                background-color:#444751;}
            </style>
        </head>
            <body>
               <div class="Line">
                  <hr>
               </div>
               <div class="Bat">
                  <b>BATTERIES</b>
               </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```